# How to display array content at the end of getjson call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, getjson

i have a function that makes 2 getjson calls and writes the responses to an array . i used the following code at the end of my second getjson call:

```
alert(files.length);
print_r(files);
console.log(files);
```

However , the files.length tells me the number of items in the array but print_r(files); and console.log are not working ? i want to print the array items to confirm i got correct items but array print doesn't work ! could any one tell me how to fix this problem ?( my goal is to later on sort this array and remove duplicates and filter... )

```
    <script>
    var files = new Array();

       function pushtoArray(){

    //first getjson call
    var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json"; 
        $.getJSON(url1, function(data) {

          var entry = data.feed.entry;

          $(entry).each(function(){
            // Column names are name, age, etc.
        count++;
         files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });

            $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$url.$t+'</p>');

          });

        alert(files.length);
        print_r(files);
        console.log(files);
        });//end of ajax call

    //second getjson call
var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json"; 
        $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {

          var entry = data.feed.entry;

          $(entry).each(function(){
            // Column names are name, age, etc.
        count++;
         files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });

            $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$url.$t+'</p>');

          });

        alert(files.length);
        print_r(files);
        console.log(files);
        });//end of ajax call


        };//end of function

    </javascript>
```

html code:

```
<body onload="pushtoArray()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Print_r is a PHP function, in javascript you can only use console.log.

Comment: thanks for reply. How i can use the array outside the ajax ? for example inside another function ?

Comment: For that, you should put it in a non-local variable, I guess. (Local variables have the prefix "var").
You should keep in mind that Ajax-calls are asynchronous, so the code between getJSON and the end of the ajax call, is executed a bit later than the other code in your script (because it just keeps executing when it has initiated the Ajax-call).

Comment: How to wait for all multiple getjson calls to finish before sending array to another function?

Comment: It might be getting a bit off-topic here. Maybe you should post a new question or search for the solution yourself.
But... I'll help you a bit: You can create an array (so not a local one) and put your JSON results in it. When you did 5 requests and the JSON array contains 5 items, then you know all requests have finished and you can throw the array to a function. Got that?